# How to use external libraries in LWC with inner class (function)

Tags: lightning-web-components, libraries, third-party

I wanted to use this library https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/ in lwc, uploaded it as static resource

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import LeaderLineJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/LeaderLineJS';
```

And loaded it in renderedCallback, looks ok, and it gives success, even I can see loaded file in chrome devtools

```
if(!this.isScriptLoaded) {
    Promise.all([loadScript(this, LeaderLineJS)]).then(() => {
        console.log('script loaded');   
        this.isScriptLoaded= true;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error');
    })
}
```

But when I try to create new instance

```
randomLine(e){
    let actionItems = this.template.querySelectorAll('.actionItem');
    let line = new LeaderLine(
        actionItems[1],
        actionItems[2]
      );
    console.log(line);
}
```

It gives me an error that LeaderLine is not defined, what am I missing? I don`t understand, Thanks in advance. (Of course, I tried this lib locally, it works fine)

Comment: When is the randomLine function being called?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Promise is an asynchronous operation, you may be trying to use LeaderLine before the script has been loaded.

Depending on how you're calling the `randomLine(e)` function, you may want to either wrap your page in an `if:true={isScriptLoaded}`, or call random from withn the Promise.then() function.

I'd need more information about how/when the randomLine function is called to be more specific.